# Are Klytus and his Secret Police some kind of androids?

Tags: flash-gordon

In the 1980 film "[**Flash Gordon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film))", the head of Ming the Merciless' secret police is a being named Klytus. A rather unemotional guy, Klytus is nevertheless capable of anger, jealousy and lust. We never see him out of his robes or mask, but we do see him

> die rather gruesomely when impaled by spikes on Sky City's fighting platform.

During closeups of the secret police, they appear to not have lower jaws, resembling only the upper portion of a golden skull. In neither case do they seem exactly human, and at one point we see an agent with wires behind his goggles (although that may have been a special case).

[image]

**Are Klytus and his men human, or are they supposed to be some sort of androids?**

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about rewatching this this weekend, but here's my off the cuff response, not having watched *Flash Gordon* in some years.

The character of Klytus was created for the 1980 film.  He does not appear in the old comics or film serials, which would normally be the sources I would look to for additional canonical information.  So we have to look at the evidence in the film.

Given the time the movie was made, it is pretty obvious that General Klytus was supposed to be a character in the mold of Darth Vader.  His face is unseen, and he wears a robotic-looking mask.  Parts of his body appear to be robotic, particularly the immobile golden right arm.  The fact that his left arm looks more normal suggests strongly that, Klytus, like Vader, is a human with some artificial parts.

The other secret police officers are presumably similar (being faceless like imperial stormtroopers).  However, being less powerful and evil than Klytus, they have fewer manifestly inhuman body parts.